# How to make a login and signup page using an existing model in Django==2.1

Tags: django, django-models

I am a making a student management system with django. I have a `Student` model which should be modified only by the registrar when a student takes admission. The registrar will use the inbuilt django admin page to add students.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    roll = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER, default='O', max_length=1)
    dob = models.DateField(null=False, help_text='YYYY-MM-DD', blank=False)
    admission_type = models.CharField(choices=ADMISSION_TYPES, default='B', max_length=1)
```

Now I want to be able to use this model to make a login and signup page for students.

In the signup page, the student enters his valid roll number and a password.

In the login page he must enter this roll and password to go to his dashboard.

How can I do this efficiently? I have tried extending `AbstractUser` but I am unable to make it work.

Comment: What is not working with extending `AbstractUser`? This is documented in: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project

Comment: In the signup page, a student should enter his valid roll number given to him by the registrar to setup his password, how do I check this? Should I store the new password entered by the student in the same model? Should I create a new class that extends AbstractUser  and have the roll field as OneToOne field?